# In C, what does it actually do when you input a string but print it out as integer?

Tags: arrays, c, string

In this code below, I input a string but have it converted to integer and print it out.

```
int main ()
{
   int v6[4];
   printf ("Enter a string: ");
   int i = scanf ("%s",v6);  
   printf ("%d ",v6[0]);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a string: tom
7171956
```

What did it actually do?

Comment: There is no conversion whatsoever done here.

Comment: `int v6[4];` is the wrong type as a target for `%s`.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Werror ...`) and fix all warnings

Comment: @4386427 the OP claims he "has it converted to integer", but there _is_ no conversion done here.

Comment: @4386427 excatly. I think we can delete out comments regarding this.

Comment: It caused undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Take your answer

```
7171956
```

convert it to hex

```
0x6d6f74
```

Check an ascii table

```
mot
```

You have filled  the memory with the the ascii representation of `tom` then you read it as an integer, taking byte order into account.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening here: (assuming `int` is a 32 bit type on your platform):

`int v6[4]` takes 16 bytes in memory.

After your `scanf` with `tom` as input, the first n bytes of `v6` look like this: (x being an undetermined value).

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----
| 't' | 'o' | 'm' |  0  |  x  |  x  |  x  |  x  | ...
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----
```

The same thing in hexadécimal (0x74 being the ASCII code for the letter 't' etc.):

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----
| 74  |  6F |  6D |  0  |  x  |  x  |  x  |  x  | ...
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----
```

The value `0x6d6f74` (which is `v6[0]`) converted to decimal is `7171956`.

Be aware that on a *big endian* (google that term) architeture `v[0]` would be `0x746f6d00`.

But don't do these kind of things, it's *undefined behaviour* (also google that).